# Ubuntu 14.10 - Create an FTP Account

Tags: ftp

I've searched a lot of websites and have found no answers. How can I create just a normal FTP account (which can be used on Port 22 for Filezilla aswell as the SSH) that is in the folder "/home/hisname"? I want it to only be able to make files in that directory and run them, and make it so he can't mess with any other parts of the system.

I've really been searching all morning. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have an FTP server installed, a regular user should be able to use it in authenticated mode - no special qualities needed.

https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/ftp-server.html

Answer (score 1):

This depends on which ftp daemon you use. Normally, FTP accounts are just the normal accounts you use to log in to your machine. You can change a standard user's login directory by modifying /etc/passwd, for example, or when creating the new user.